Want to verify it's IMPOSSIBLE to use a Mac mini 2018 or later with ARD without connecting display, keyboard, & mouse
I've already done tons of experimentation with this and feel mostly confident I know the answer and I have done searches on here to make sure this is not a duplicate query.
I recently replaced my Mac mini 2018 with the new Mac mini M4. My Plex server has been running on a Mac Pro Tower (2009) for years and it's not IF but when it gives up the ghost. So I figured I'd repurpose the 2018 Mac mini to be my new Plex server with an external 4 drive raid box. Since it will be pretty much just an always running server I see no need to have a display, keyboard, and mouse always attached after I get it all set up. I have several Macs in the house in different locations and they all work great with ARD but the are full systems with display, keyboards, and pointing devices. All of them give me pretty much full control including being able to reboot them remotely, and log back in remotely.
But after several days of trying different ways of doing this including plugging in a HDMI dummy connector to simulate a display it appears the only way I can do this on this Mac mini is to keep a mouse, keyboard, and display plugged in all the time. I know I could keep all that stuff unplugged and nearby after getting it going but the pain of pulling them out and using them to reset the system would be such a pain and I really don't have the space for the display and keyboard and mouse to be sitting around.
I've disabled much of the built-in security thinking that would be the issue -- but no. And by default every time a remote access attempt is made that does not work because everything is not plugged into it, the Mac goes into recovery and I have to plug all that stuff back in to get it up and running back to the login screen.
SO... is it the case I'm reduced to leaving a keyboard and mouse and display plugged into it all the time and just hide it away behind the rack we have everything supporting our home office in?
I just want to be sure I've not overlooked something. I've tried every variation and combination of setups I can and every time I'm having to reboot the Mac with all its accessories to get it to work again.

Not sure I understand the setup. Do you have the mini running all the time or do you boot it each time you need the plex server? You can easily run a Mini without external devices, would assume you don't need to reboot it very often.

I believe ARD in this context is Apple Remote Desktop. AFAIK there's no reason ARD shouldn't be working when headless; could you clarify exactly what happens when you try to connect with ARD when the machine is headless?

It doesn’t make sense you can remotely reboot the M4 mini - newer Mac’s boot to firmware only. You need a KVM or to stage a one time log in credential in Secure Enclave, T2, NVRAM to allow an unattended boot, unlock of the encrypted storage and sign the user in.

From your post it's hard to determine what your problem is. I went the same route this year. Replaced my Mac Pro 2009 Plex Server with a Mac Mini M2. I've got a HDMI dummy connected and everything works fine. SSH and Screen Sharing (not ARD)  all good. Only thing is unexpected reboots. For those I need to enter the FileVault password, but I can do that blindly or use Yubikey with keystroke entry. But even that I do blind. Just to be sure I use sudo fdesetup authrestart -delayminutes 0 for planned reboots.

The setup is not impossible. It’s unlikely anyone not able to put hands on your hardware can solve this (even if you make a dozen updates to the post and we play 20 questions in the comments).
The hardware will work for ARD if you first connect everything and get ARD running. When you disconnect the display, the resolution goes back to the basic but you can still connect over ARD.
Since your results are different, you need to fix your software, your process or consider a hardware repair.

I would start with undoing whatever you think you needed to do to modify security
If that doesn’t sort things, do a complete factory wipe and install clean macOS: install nothing, don’t bother with iCloud or apps, enable ARD only to ensure you know if you need hardware repair or not.

The only reason you need keyboard and display is one time for initial setup and periodically for reboots where the Mac is at a pre-boot firmware screen and the OS isn’t running at all.

TL;DR I already had an available keyboard, trackpad, and display plug. So why beat my head against the wall ... I got a $100 display from Amazon, found a place to keep it all set up, and gave up on having it headless.

Those of you that attempted to assist me... thank you greatly.
I've been able to use several models of Macs in the past quite successfully and easily with no more than a dummy VGA or DVI or HDMI display plug left plugged in with no need for a mouse or keyboard. So having tried every reasonable combination of strategies, I can say having a practical solution for running a Mac mini 2018 headless running the latest OS 15.x is not practical.
It simply would not respond to ARD unless I had the fake monitor adapter, keyboard, and mouse connected. Once ARD found it, I could unplug the keyboard and mouse with no problems, and it would remain accessible. But reboot it, and you are back to having those input/output devices attached to get it to do anything other than going directly to recovery as if you had forgotten the password. Yes, I tried it with all the high security settings disabled.
At this point in the Mac's evolution, Apple is not keen on having headless active platforms that don't appear to be sitting in front of a user. And, from a practical standpoint, it works out fine for me, and I wish I had given up on trying to get it to work to begin with.

huzzah? Sorry you had to resort to a display.
